# Chamar uma única vez um método dentro de um event handler que é chamado várias vezes?

Tags: c#, método

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para garantir que um *método* seja chamado uma única vez dentro de um `Event Handler` C#, considerando que esse `Event` é chamado várias vezes.

Exemplo:

```
//meuEventHandler é chamado várias vezes.
meuEventHandler = (object sender, MeuEventArgs e) =>
{

    helloWord();
};
```

Ou seja eu quero chamar o método ***helloWord()*** uma única vez

Comment: Seria interessante tu melhorar esse controle, talvez evitar tantas chamadas ou controlar cada chamada pra um evento diferente se for possível. Se não, pode criar um `bool` pra controlar se o evento há foi chamado.

Comment: @Gabriel Weber eu já tentei usar um 'bool' para fazer o controle e também tentei usar o 'lock', infelizmente nenhuma das duas formas funcionou, esse 'Event Handler' descobre serviços de um dispositivo **Bluetooth Low Energy**, e são uns 9 serviços, então ele é chamado pelo menos 9 vezes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode dar um `unsubscribe` no evento após ele ser executado pela primeira vez.

Algo como:

```
EventHandler meuEventHandler = null;
meuEventHandler = (object sender, MeuEventArgs e) =>
{    
    helloWord();
    c.Click -= meuEventHandler;
};
c.Click += meuEventHandler;
```

Comment: Isso resolveu o problema Vinícius, muito obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 1):

Caso queira uma solução mais genérica, usando `Closures` junto da solução do [jbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/18246/jbueno), aqui está:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        EventHandler @event = EventHandlerHelper.Once((object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Somente uma vez");
        });

        @event.Invoke(null, null);
        @event.Invoke(null, null);
    }
}

public static class Functional
{
    public static Action<T1, T2> Once<T1, T2>(Action<T1, T2> action)
    {
        var executed = false;

        return (T1 arg1, T2 arg2) => {
            if (!executed)
            {
                action(arg1, arg2);
                executed = true;
            }
        };
    }
}

public static class EventHandlerHelper
{
    public static EventHandler Once(Action<object, EventArgs> action)
    {
        return Functional.Once(action).Invoke;
    }
}
```

Para ver funcionando, [aqui está](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BffgJb).

Answer (score 0):

O certo seria evitar essas chamadas "extras". Sem mais detalhes é impossível te dizer com certeza o que deveria ser feito, mas, atendendo ao teu pedido. Apenas crie uma variável no escopo da classe para controllr isso.

```
private bool HelloWorldExecutado = false;

meuEventHandler = (object sender, MeuEventArgs e) =>
{
    if(!HelloWorldExecutado)
    {
        helloWord();
        HelloWorldExecutado = true;
    }
};
```